# Capture & Decrypt packets captured by monitoring mode

Tags: wireshark, monitoring, decryption

I am working on capturing packets using monitoring mode on my laptop. The problem is that I cannot get the source/destination IP's since the packets are encrypted. I added a key and it didn't work (I am using **Wireshark** to do this).

1- Is there an alternative way to do it?

2- Is there a way I can do it wirelessly using command line (terminal in my case)?

3- Can I sniff all packets on my network by connecting my laptop via ethernet?

Comment: Source/Destination IP's cannot be encrypted as that would break TCP/IP.

Comment: @user2320464 I think it's safe to assume that we are talking about some form of wireless encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Some assumptions I'm going to make: You are capturing wirelessly, on a WPA-PSK network and they "key" is the pre shared key aka password.

When you capture traffic wirelessly a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) is used during the authentication process known as the [4 way handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004). During this process niether the client nor the access point actually send the password but instead both prove that they know it. The nonce serves as a way to make this process unique each time.

**The result of this process is that even if you have they pre shared key, you cannot decrypt the traffic unless you also have the four way handshake.**

My sugguestion would be to retry your test and ensure that you have the 4 way hanshake as part of your pcap. For help with this process [check out this source](http://mrncciew.com/2014/08/16/decrypt-wpa2-psk-using-wireshark/). For further information regarding your question [there is this thread](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201204/msg00092.html).

Comment: I am just interested in the source and destinations, either IP or MAC address. I will review those links and leave a feedback. Thanks a lot